# How to make Property Mapping Defaults apply during inserts using Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have this mapping:
 Map(x => x.FileAs).Length(200).Default("").Not.Nullable();

The database schema already exists and the column does not allow nulls and has no default value. Changing the live database isn't an option.

Can NHibernate be configured to set the values to the specified default during insert if the current value is null?

The documentation for Fluent NHibernate is extremely brief... And my searches thus far haven't indicated if this is possible or not.

Thanks, 
Aaron

Answer (score 2):

You cant make NHibernate to set default values. `Default("")` in mappings affect only DB schema that can be generated by NHibernate.

If you need enforce some default value for the property in the entities, why don't you do it in constructor?

Comment: In this case the values are read from another source where they can be null. And it would be cleaner to keep the server side mapping including those for the defaults together in the one mapping configuration class.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I believe you can.  You should check out the following in your mappings:

> (7)    dynamic-update (optional, defaults to false): Specifies that
>   UPDATE SQL should be generated at runtime and contain only those
>   columns whose values have changed.
>
> (8)    dynamic-insert (optional, defaults to false): Specifies that
>   INSERT SQL should be generated at runtime and contain only the columns
>   whose values are not null.

Above was taken from here: http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-class

Fluent example:

```
public class OrderMap : ClassMap<Order>
{
    public OrderMap()
    {
        DynamicInsert();
        DynamicUpdate();
        Table("ORDER");
        Id(x => x.OrderId, "ORDER_ID");
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will then ignore the property altogether as it's null and the database will complain that it can't be null.  What I'd like is for NHibernate on insert to include the column with the default value when it sees it's null.

Comment: That is what database defaults are for!  If NHibernate doesn't include it in the insert it will default to the database default.

Comment: I've also found that Map(x => Order.Details).Length(500) doesn't trim the text, where the underlying database column is ntext.  So does NHibernate provide for data conversion. Can I register a data converter class for a column? Granted all this in the database is better but some cases conversion is needed and I'd like it to be an extension of the mapping rather than a completely different system.

Comment: Yeah all the stuff in the mapping files like Length() and Default() is only for the generation of the database script.  It does not actually apply these rules to your entities.